# Mouse over jquery for view sub level items

Tags: jquery, css

Tile 4 sub `<ul>` will be visible on hover of Tile 4 `<li>` when I quickly move the pointer to sub `<ul>` it's showing. How can I avoid hiding sub ul if I move slowly to sub level using jQuery?

https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/8qkt6b07/22/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 //Fade effect
    $(".tile_nav  li").hover(function () {
        $(this).siblings().css("opacity", .5);
    
  
    }, function () {
        $(this).siblings().css("opacity", 1);
  
    });
});
```

```css
.tile_nav {
    width:241px;
    list-style:none;
}
.tile_nav li {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:0 1px 1px 0;
}
.tile_nav li a {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    display:block;
}
.tile_subnav li {
    background:red;
}
.tile_nav li ul {
    display:none;
    margin:2px;
}
.tile_nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tile_nav">
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile 4</a>
       <ul class="tile_subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1 of Tile 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2 of Tile 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that even without **jquery**.

The **easiest way** is to change `margin: 2px;` to `border: 2px solid transparent;` in your `.tile_nav li ul` style.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/8qkt6b07/43/).**

**E.g.**

**Instead of:**

```
.tile_nav li ul {
    display:none; 
    margin: 2px;
}
```

**Change it to:**

```
.tile_nav li ul {
    display:none; 
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

**By the way,** I saw a problem with the **submenu list** next to the **first item**. If you move your cursor slowly to the submenu list next to the **first item** the **submenu list** disappears.


To **solve this** problem, try **adding this css**:

```
.tile_nav li ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Animation sample: [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/8qkt6b07/44/)**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The margin is your problem. When the pointer goes over the blank space, hover ends. Try without margins and some borders instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by making sure your mouse pointer never leaves the triggering `li` (and its child `ul`). To do that, remove the top margin of `2px` from the child `ul`, otherwise there is 2px space between the elements which does neither belong to the parent `li` nor to the child `ul`.

```
.tile_nav li ul {
    display:none;
    margin: 0 2px 2px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8qkt6b07/23/

### Edit: Here's a much nicer version with an easier way to position the subnav and some fancy transition action:

https://jsfiddle.net/8qkt6b07/41/

Comment: That margin required. how to solve with jquery setTimeout

Comment: function myFunction () {
     $(".tile_subnav").css("display", "none !important");alert("test");
}
$(".four").mouseleave(function () {
               // Code to do stuff immediately
               setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
            });

});

https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/8qkt6b07/37/

Comment: Why is it required? Check my fiddles, also the second one, which is far cleaner and removes some more problems in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result. Set position:relative on the li and position:absolute on the sub menu.

I updated your css:

```
.tile_nav { width:241px; list-style:none; }
.tile_nav li { width:60px; height:60px; float:left; list-style:none; margin:0 1px 1px 0; background:#ccc; position: relative;}
.tile_nav li a { width:60px; height:60px; display:block;  }
.tile_subnav li { background:red;}
.tile_nav li ul {display:none; position: absolute; top: 62px;}
.tile_nav li:hover ul {display:block;}
```